# ElasticSearch 1.7.5 doesn't start

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, networking

I've just download elasticsearch 1.7.5 version. And trying to start it on **default** settings, it fails with:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.0.2:9300
```

If I setup my custom settings such as

```
network.bind_host: 192.168.0.1
network.publish_host: 192.168.0.1
network.host: 192.168.0.1
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
http.enabled: false
```

It says

```
{1.7.5}: Startup Failed ...
- BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9300]]
    ChannelException[Failed to bind to: /192.168.0.1:9300]
        BindException[Cannot assign requested address]
```

And I can't see any processes are holding that port

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 9300
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you try setting the host in the config to 192.168.0.2 (as that's the ip shown in the first error message)?

Comment: Can you try doing lsof -i :9300

Comment: @bless yes it works, but actually I'm interested why does it not start on default settings. It is not clear what is wrong with my system and why does ES start looking for another ip address

Comment: @Viraj Parab it prints a lot of data, like 100 lines such as:
"TCP localhost:53338->localhost:9300 (ESTABLISHED)"

Comment: just get the process ID which is working on that port by doing lsof -i :9300 and kill that process